# Outbound Message Nack - will other messages send?

Tags: workflowoutboundmessage

If I receive a nack in an outbound message, with Salesforce send later messages that are under that same message, or does one nack in the queue block any use of that message?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

delivery for OM doesn't preserve order, individual messages have a time based back off if they are nacked, this doesn't affect other messages in the queue. However if you repeatedly nack messages or have a slow ack response time, your queue can end up getting put in the sin bin, where delivery attempts are slower, and retry back-offs are larger, and that'll affect all messages in the queue.